# How do I describe an Action<T> delegate that returns a value (non-void)?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

The `Action<T>` delegate return void. Is there any other built-in delegate which returns non void value?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes. `Func<>` returns the type specified as the final generic type parameter, such that `Func<int>` returns an `int` and `Func<int, string>` accepts an integer and returns a string. Examples:

```
Func<int> getOne = () => 1;
Func<int, string> convertIntToString = i => i.ToString();
Action<string> printToScreen = s => Console.WriteLine(s);
// use them

printToScreen(convertIntToString(getOne()));
```

Answer (score 20):

Sure, the Func Delegates return T.

```
Func<TResult> is "TResult method()"
Func<TInput, TResult> is "TResult method(TInput param)"
```

All the way down to

```
Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534303.aspx

Also, for the sake of completeness, there is Predicate which returns bool.

```
Predicate<T> is "bool method(T param)"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx

Comment: Also, in .NET 4, `Func<>` can be `Func<T1,... T16, TResult>` The prior limit was T4.

Comment: Also, for *complete* completeness, don't forget [`Converter(TInput, TOutput)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y.aspx) and [`Comparison(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) (both obviously predating `Func<T1, T2>` and `Func<T1, T2, T3>`, which renders them obsolete). Actually, there are probably more than that...

Comment: @Dan very true, although they are very specific due to their naming (which is all there really is to it). I used Converter once: http://www.stum.de/2009/12/23/using-a-converter-to-convert-from-a-model-to-a-business-class/

Comment: Yeah, it always struck me as kind of strange though that a lot of the LINQ extension methods take a `Func<T, bool>` parameter called `predicate`. On a related note, I once (in my dark times) actually started to write a `ConvertAll<TIn, TOut>` function that took an `IEnumerable<TIn>` and spit out an `IEnumerable<TOut>` with the assistance of a `Converter<TIn, TOut>`... until I (quickly) realized that this is exactly what `Select` already does. Foiled by the identical delegates!