# Update a specific property with generics (Winform C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

Apologies as I am new to generics (which is what I believe is needed in this scenario).

I want to pass the BindingList variable to a method that performs an update on a defined property, and then returns a pass/fail (true/false) value. This appears to be harder than I thought it would be, so could use some help. Here is working and non-working code.

First, I have a class with a BindingList (working):

```
public class BookMetaData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _bookMetaDataTitle;
    [DescriptionLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookMetaDataTitleComment")]
    [DisplayNameLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookMetaDataTitleDisplayName")]
    public string BookMetaDataTitle { get { return _bookMetaDataTitle; } set { SetField(ref _bookMetaDataTitle, value, "BookMetaDataTitle"); } }

    #region handle property changes
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        //if the value did not change, do nothing.
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        //the value did change, so make the modification.
        field = value;
        return true;
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Next, I create a variable that represents the binding list (working):

```
BindingList<BookMetaData> bookMetaData = new BindingList<BookMetaData>(); //metadata for the books
```

Prepare to send the class variable and specific property to update to a generic method. Please note, this technically works, but the remaining code does not:

```
private bool Test()
{
    //the code below would probably be in a foreach loop and would not pass a single index.
    ProcessBookTitle(bookMetaData, 0, typeof(BookMetaData).GetProperty(nameof(BookMetaData.BookMetaDataCoverage)));
    return true;
}
```

I want this generic method (is it called a method?) to update the BindingList class variable's specified property. If something goes wrong in the general business logic, that return false. Otherwise, return true (not working):

```
private void ProcessBookTitle<T>(BindingList<T> bindingList, int classIndex, PropertyInfo prop)
{
    try
    {
        //do some things...
        //If I manually wrote the next line, it would look like this:
        //bookMetaData[0].BookMetaDataTitle = "My Book Title";
        bindingList[classIndex].prop = "My Book Title"; //error = 'T' does not contain the information for 'prop'...
        //maybe do some other things...
        return true; //cannot find a way to return bool.
    }
        catch
        {
            //something went wrong somewhere, so return false.
            return false; //does not work because cannot return a bool.
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can send the name of the class variable and the property to update to another method? Also, is it possible to do this within a method that returns bool (and or some other way of returning success or failure)?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

**EDIT:** The requirement to return a bool is to ensure the passing method knew whether the overall process was successful. Updated code to show this.

Comment: You can use reflection. But how do you decide to return `true` or `false`? What does it mean to fail to set the property value? If an exception is thrown in the property setter?

Comment: That is a good point for me to clarify. You should assume there is other login in that method that performs functions like reading a file from a disk or parsing through information. If there is a failure during that process, return true or false.

Comment: Which method? The `SetField` method? The `BookMetaDataTitle` property for example calls this method but ignores the return value.

Comment: Perhaps I am not using the proper terminology. What I am calling the `Test` method calls the `ProcessBookTitle` method. When `ProcessBookTitle` runs, I want it to update the specific property for the passed class variable. I also want the `Test` method to know that all the code ran properly in the `ProcessBookTitle` method. Does this make sense? I apologize if I am using the term method in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection for this as @Yacoub Massad mention. If you are wondering how then it's like this. What we are doing here is getting the type of generic type T and access its property information. Now since you mentioned reading from file, parsing information etc, I suggest you look into [Delegate Actions With Return Values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4161690/3881866). But that it self is another story to tell.

```
    static private bool ProcessBookTitle<T>(BindingList<T> bindingList, int classIndex, string propertyName) 
        where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

            object val = "Do some processing whatever here.";

            propertyInfo.SetValue(bindingList[classIndex], Convert.ChangeType(val, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do something with the exception

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: or you can simply add another parameter to the method named val of type object and assign it to the Convert.ChangeType(val ...

Comment: Thank you very much @John, this worked. I further enhanced your code so I did not have to call with a string. The calling method looks like this: `ProcessBookTitle(bookMetaData, 0, typeof(BookMetaData).GetProperty(nameof(BookMetaData.BookMetaDataTitle)));` This allowed me to remove the `where T : class`, the `Type type = typeof(T);` row, and the `PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);` row. Do you see any problems with this? The code runs, so I think it is okay :-)

Comment: If it works then it works. No problems at all. But the reason why we used generics <T> is so that the method will work for different classes not just for type BookMetaData. In case you have another list of type XXX you can use the same method. As much as possible I would suggest using the generic version as I posted above so in the future in case you need the same functionality for a different class you can re-use it.

Comment: Well, since you named it ProcessBookTitle then your modifications seems more appropriate. :-)

Comment: Okay thank you very much. Ultimately, the name of it will probably be something like `GetSingleNodeFromHtml` which is even more generic. Thank you very much for the fast and very helpful response. I am learning a lot every day, and by learning, I mean stumbling sometimes :-)